# Frozen while loop

Tags: java, iterator, jena

I have an issue with a while loop. Here's the code:

```
ExtendedIterator<Statement> statementIt = m.listStatements(null, p, obj);
Statement stamt = null;
List<Resource> lres = new ArrayList<Resource>();
System.out.println("\tdebugging: going into the while");
int counter = 0; 
while (statementIt.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("\tdebugging: statementIt.hasNext()? " + statementIt.hasNext());
    System.out.println("\t\tdebugging: \t started round " + counter);
    stamt = (Statement)statementIt.next();
    if(!lres.contains((Resource)stamt.getSubject()))
        lres.add((Resource)stamt.getSubject());
    counter++;
    System.out.println("\t\tdebugging: counter is next at " + counter);
    System.out.println("\t\tdebugging: will be next? " + statementIt.hasNext());
    System.out.println("dadada dbdbdb");
}
System.out.println("\tdebugging: came out of the while alive!");
```

I know for a fact that there are only 3 iterations to be done, so the var `counter` should add up to 3 and then it would get out of the loop, but when the counter becomes 3 and it is time to execute `hasNext()` the program freezes.

I don't know if I'm passing by something vital or basic but I'm pulling my hair over this :(

**Edit:**

It should execute the loop 2 times, not 3. So it is something related to the `hasNext()` execution, I would say.
Here's is the "new" body of the while loop I used to deduce this:

```
stamt = (Statement)statementIt.next();
if(!lres.contains((Resource)stamt.getSubject()))
    lres.add((Resource)stamt.getSubject());
counter++;
System.out.println("\t\tdebugging: this loop subject was " + ((Resource)stamt.getSubject()).toString());
```

which prints 2 times and get frozen when trying to print for the 3rd time.

**Edit2:**

Here's the C# code that does this without problems:

```
ExtendedIterator statementIt = m.listStatements(null, p, obj);
int quantity = 0;
Statement stamt = null;
List<Resource> lres = new List<Resource>();
while (statementIt.hasNext())
{
    stamt = (Statement)statementIt.next();
    quantity++;
    if(!lres.Contains((Resource)stamt.getSubject()))
        lres.Add((Resource)stamt.getSubject());
}
```

**Edit3:**

it absolutely has something to do with the iterators (changed `ExtendedIterator<Statement>` to `StmtIterator` for supposedly better performance, not relevant to the issue at hands). I will show the prints of the subsequent statements:

```
[http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#BibRef2, http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#pointsAt, http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#Doc2]
[http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#BibRef1, http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#pointsAt, http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#Doc2]
[-75c480c5:151c9f1b5af:-7f54, http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#pointsAt, http://practicum/luis/ontologies/2015/8/document#Doc2]
```

That last print is unwanted. That subject (first element compounded of hexadecimals) should not be considered by the iterator, should not be in the list. That is a memory space (I guess) and not related to the OntModel loaded by reading my .rdf file >:(

What the hell is wrong with these tools of the Jena Package????

Comment: Why not run this in a debugger, and when it hangs, stop and check *where* in hasNext() it's blocking ?

Comment: Which type does `m` have?

Comment: Please add the hasNext() code so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: I considered the profiling plugin an option, I was gonna work on it after posting the question.
`m` is an `OntModel`, a jena package class
As for the `hasNext()` code... I guess the one provided by the javadoc of ExtendedIterator(?)

Comment: It seems likely that your `OntModel` is corrupt in some way. Perhaps you have some kind of self/recursive reference in it.

Comment: That cannot be. I have a C# program that does exactly this deed and it runs perfectly. So the problem is not with the file but with my Java program or transcription of the original in C#

Comment: Could it possibly be: `lres.add((Resource)stamt.getSubject());`? It looks like you might be adding more elements while you're iterating over the list so the iterator keeps returning more elements. Anyway, could you provide code to reproduce this problem? It's really hard to figure out a problem without being able to test it.

Comment: No, that cannot be the case. The list I am adding elements to is separated from the model. Consider it an array if you want to. Adding elements to this structure does not imply adding elements to my ontology (that would mean modifying my ontology (consider it a database if you want to)).
I can email you my files (the whole java program is 3772 lines long and the ontology file is 1576 lines long, also you would need to import Jena tools into the project, and those are some Mbs) if you really want to reproduce it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, problem solved.

The noted space memory printed in the last edit is actually a blank node of the ontology, so it *should* be printed. Since I only want URI Resources to be considered I should have included this kind of check.

```
if(!stamt.getSubject().isURIResource())
    break;
```

Cheers~

PS: altough the original issue has not been fixed (.hasNext() freezing the program) my specific problem has been solved and I am no longer stalled. I am now amazed that my C# program worked without issues of this kind.